# Error: Cannot find module 'node-wit'

Tags: node.js, wit.ai

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node-wit'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/NodeJS/node-wit/examples/quickstart.js:10:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

I don't know why I got that encountered error by using https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit.git

My node version is `v5.11.1`

But I installed `npm install --save node-wit` got follow error:

[image]

Comment: *How* did you use it? Did you install it? A little more detail wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Have you tried `npm install --save node-wit`? Every module on npm is not made available to your program automatically.

Comment: @sdgluck yap, I did but got error. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the quickstart-example inside the repo itself. it is requiring `node-wit` in lines 7+8, and in the catch if lines 7+8 fail.

just log the error in the catch, and you will see what went wrong. i suspect that the module itself is not working/buggy, because the require looks correct (`require(../')` will require the `index.js`)